# Make latexmk and pdfviewer robust against latex errors

Tags: errors, pdf, viewers, latexmk

Sometimes `latexmk` fails because the file was saved premature. 
For example the user forgets to close a `{` bevore he saves the `.tex` file.

The user has to get `latexmk` back on the road again and usually `evince` has to be restarted afterwards too.

Is there a trick to save evince from crashing or is there a **linux pdf viewer** with autoreload that will just ignore a broken, ampty or missing `pdf` and reload again, when it works?

Comment: SumatraPDF does handle broken PDFs very good (i.e. does not even load them). But apparently it's only for Windows.

Comment: You can use `xpdf` and the `-reload` option and only reload when the build was successful.

Comment: Could you describe further what you mean by "saved premature"? Which Linux and which version of `evince` are you running? From my experience (recent Ubuntu), `evince` is quite good at handling bad PDFs...

Comment: Sounds like a bug in evince that should be reported to it's authors [here](https://live.gnome.org/Evince/ReportingBugs). Or use okular. `:-)`